How can I change which Google account I use to pay for a subscription via Play?
I have several Google accounts logged into my phone. Some Android app such as YouTube allows user to pay for a subscription via Play. How can I change  which Google account I use to pay for a subscription via Play?

Example: YouTube allows user to pay for a subscription via Play:


I found the answer on Reddit by user AmericanEmpire:

The only thing I've found that works is to:

Delete app data (may or may not be necessary)

Delete app

Go on to a regular computer and sign on to the account you want to use

Install the app onto the device you want on the play store website through your computer


It should now be associated with the desired account. I wish Google would fix this issue.

I tried and that worked. (tested on Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra running Android 13)
Follow-up question: How can I determine which Google account is linked to a specific installed Android app?
